# How to add category filter titles in VS2019 preview VSIX?

Tags: vsix, vsixmanifest, visual-studio-2019

I have to add filter titles like below MSFT default template in my custom VS2019 VSIX.

[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Where to add this changes in my VSIX manifest or vstemplate file ?